# Display images where the location of the images are in a text file using python

Tags: python

I am new to pyhton learning CNN and would like to get your help with my problem.

I have a text file with details such as below that gives the location of the respective images that were classified,

Actual Cat Images:
output/images/IMG_1547.JPG
output/images/IMG_1548.JPG
output/images/IMG_1548.JPG
output/images/IMG_1555.JPG

Actual dog Images:
output/images/IMG_1557.JPG
output/images/IMG_1598.JPG
output/images/IMG_1538.JPG
output/images/IMG_1545.JPG

How to I write a python script to display images listed belonging to Actual Cat Images and Actual dog Images on my jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_sample_of_img(nrows, ncols, img_paths):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(ncols * 4, nrows * 4)

    for i, img_path in enumerate(img_paths):
        # Set up subplot; subplot indices start at 1
        sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)
        sp.axis('Off')  # Don't show axes (or gridlines)
        img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
        plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()


with open("cat.txt","r") as pf:
     height = width = int(sqrt(len(pf.readlines))
     plot_sample_of_img(nrows, ncols, pf.readlines)
```